# HTML email background on body not working in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, outlook, background-image, html-email, document-body

I have the following html, if i open it up on browser it works fine..but when i send it as a mail to my outlook 2013, i dont see the background..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style='background-image: url("http://postimg.org/image/t6abf7srn/");background-repeat:no-repeat'>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried options 1 and 2 given at this link : http://blog.mailermailer.com/email-design/background-images-in-html-email-the-naked-truth

Have tried the solutions at below link as well:

1) http://blog.mailermailer.com/email-design/bulletproof-email-background-images-fact-or-fiction

2) http://backgrounds.cm/

but no luck.

Just adding my VML addition as well, which doesnt seem to be working too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style='background-image: url("http://postimg.org/image/t6abf7srn/");background-repeat:no-repeat'>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:background fill="t">
   <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.example.com/background_image.jpg" />
</v:background>
<![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it just outlook 2013? have you tried any other mso versions like '07,'10?b And can you post your VML try?

Comment: Well, am just trying at 2013, as its the only requirement and we dont have other version as well to test. I will try with VML though

Answer (score 0):

HTML in Outlook is rendered by Word, not IE. And Word does not support background images in HTML.

Comment: It does. If it didn't you wouldn't see them in HTML emails everywhere. Word also uses VML (vector markup language) which can accomplish some of what Word/Outlook's HTML interpreter cannot.

Comment: actually 07 or 06 degraded back, and word stopped supporting it...not sure about 2013 support

Comment: Using a v:fill you can create background images, check out: http://backgrounds.cm/

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you've added the vml xmlns into your html tag?

`<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">`

I haven't had trouble with the snippet CM provided (placed at the top of the body)

`<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:background fill="t">
   <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.example.com/background_image.jpg" />
</v:background>
<![endif]-->`

EDIT!!

Turns out you don't even need VML for outlook body backgrounds.
`<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" bgcolor="#0088cc" background="http://imagez.biz/bkg.png">`

Comment: Well, i tried that as well, but that didnt work. I am using PutsMail  (http://putsmail.com/) to test it, when i placed my original code, it was at least showing the image in PutsMail preview, but as soon as I entered VML, it wasnt showing the image as well. I have added my VML code in my original post, in case you would like to see..

Answer (score 0):

you are pointing to a document, not an image file in your css. add the image's url instead, like this:

```
<body style='background-image: url("http://s21.postimg.org/ko0vavm93/image.jpg");background-repeat:no-repeat'>
```

however like @Dmitry Streblechenko said about support, i know outlook reverted back awhile ago and stopped supporting them. not sure about 2013 support.
i would slice that image into table pieces :)